# How to replace numeric value to the link using a vector?

Tags: r, web-scraping

Ex. link :"http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/219889.html?class=1;spanmin1=01+Jan+2011;spanval1=span;template=results;type=batting;view=innings"

I want to replace the numeric value(219889) of the above link using a vector to get different links.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

players = c(4578,272279,7133)

for (i in players) {
  read = HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/",players[i],".html?class=1;spanmin1=01+Jan+2011;spanval1=span;template=results;type=batting;view=innings"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sprintf` with `%s` or `%d`

```
sprintf("http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/%s.html?class=1;spanmin1=01+Jan+2011;spanval1=span;template=results;type=batting;view=innings",players)
```

Or `paste0`

```
paste0("http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/", players, ".html?class=1;spanmin1=01+Jan+2011;spanval1=span;template=results;type=batting;view=innings")
```

Comment: thank you..how can read the html tables on those links.I tried like below,    readHTMLTable(paste0("http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/", players, ".html?class=1;spanmin1=01+Jan+2011;spanval1=span;template=results;type=batting;view=innings"))

Comment: @Kusal Check `rvest` package. It is helpful for scraping. There are functions `read_html` and `html_table()` which might be helpful.